# Factory Girl, Mongoid, and Embedded Documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid, factory-bot

I am setting up my first app with Mongoid and Devise. I am trying to Factory a user in my test with this factory:

```
Factory.define(:user) do |f|
  f.email "bob1234@example.com"
  f.password "testing"
  f.password_confirmation "testing"
end
```

When I try and factory this I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_on_blank' for []:Array
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:213:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:213:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/relations/embedded/many.rb:373:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/relations/embedded/many.rb:373:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/named_scope.rb:121:in `with_scope'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/relations/embedded/many.rb:372:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/relations/embedded/many.rb:372:in `method_missing'
```

My models look like:

User:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  embeds_many :errors
end
```

Error:

```
class Error
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :klass, :type => String
  embedded_in :user
end
```

How should a user model be created without creating any embedded documents at the same time?

Comment: If you rename "Error" to something like "Laptop" do you still get the error?

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't try that. thank you

Comment: Since you figured this out, please write an answer and accept it.